# sencha touch package build -  just displays the command prompt does not display any errors

Tags: android, sencha-touch, native, packaging

I have been working on this problem for days, and I cannot work it out.. please help ?

I followed the getting started tutorial on http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started

I successfully created the GS project .. sencha generate app GS ../GS

Now I am trying to create an .apk file, so I install on my Android handset for testing.

Problem : When I type in the following c:\sencha-touch-2> sencha package build c:\GS\packager.json

Nothing happerns and the cursor just goes to the command prompt

Below is my packager.json file.

If anybody had any ideas or can help , I would really appreciate it

```
{
    "applicationName":"GS",
    "applicationId":"com.steve.GS",
    "versionString":"1.0",
    "iconName":"Icon.png",
    "inputPath":"c:\GS",
    "outputPath":"c:\Build",
    "configuration":"Debug",
    "platform":"Android",
    "deviceType":"Universal",
    "certificatePath":"c:\debug.keystore",
    "certificateAlias":"",
    "sdkPath":"c:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk",
    "androidAPILevel":"15",
    "orientations": [
        "portrait",
        "landscapeLeft",
        "landscapeRight",
        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, because there is no output from the command, giving a solution is a bit tricky. Can you try to add more debugging by adding --debug to your build command? One possible problem could be the space in 'Program files'. Maybe you can try to put the sdk in a directory without spaces in it eg C:\utils\sencha-touch (working on mac myself, so I cannot test this)

Answer (score 0):

Try running "sencha package build packager.json" in c:\GS

if this doesn't work:

- do you habe the latest Sencha-Cmd installed?
- What sencha touch are you using 2.0.1? (I didn't find any info on android packaging for 2.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

To build a sencha touch application, make sure you update your packager.json file in the sencha touch project with the following attributes:

- "applicationId":"com.test.projectname",(package format to be followed
  here)
- "platform":"Android", ( if you are building for android device)
- "platform":"AndroidEmulator", ( if you are building for android
  emulator)
- "certificatePath":"../", (path to your certificate - can use the key
  which is used to sign android application)
- "certificatePassword":"******", (password to your key)
- "sdkPath":"../../../../../../android-sdk_r16-windows/android-sdk-windows",
  (path to android sdk if you are building for android)
- **Ensure that you are giving a relative path from the packager.json folder unlike in the question where the physical location to the sdk and key is provided**